# Outer Join issue

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of problem understanding outer join, I think. This is a school-related problem; usually I don't ask those here, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a table `Customer`, which includes `customerID`, and other customer info.
I also have a table named `Orders`, which includes `customerID`, what was bought, and how many.

Now, I just want to list all the customers who haven't bought anything, (That is, their customer ID is not in the **Orders** table.)

Can you help?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You can use an outer join to answer this, but I'd normally think in terms of listing all the customers found in the customers table whose ID is 'NOT IN' the list of customer IDs found in the order table.  This is stated in the question — you should know (or find out about) the keyword IN.

Comment: And what would the outer join statement look like? because my SELECT * FROM Customer LEFT OUTER JOIN Order.customerID ON Customer.customerID is clearly wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the indexes you have, there are few ways to do this:

OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT a.customerid
FROM   customer a
       LEFT JOIN orders b
              ON ( a.customerid = b.customerid )
WHERE  b.customerid IS NULL
```

SUBSET QUERY

```
SELECT customerid
FROM   customer
WHERE  customerid NOT IN (SELECT customerid
                          FROM   orders)
```

SET DIFFERENCE

```
SELECT customerid
FROM   customer
EXCEPT
SELECT customerid
FROM   orders
```

First method may be actually the worst in terms of performance, third is the easiest I think, but you cant retrieve additional info about customer, the second is probably the same as third in terms of performance, and still you can retrieve additional customer info.

Comment: Can you describe the result you get?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN Order o USING (customerID)
WHERE o.customerID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use outer join in this case. Try this instead

```
Select * From Customer Where CustomerId not in (Select CustomerId in Order)
```

Comment: But for the purpose of learning, how would one use it to do the same?

Comment: @Snowflow, than you should try the answer of nosid. He gave the answer to achieve this with left join it also called left outer join

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Customer.* From Customer
Left Join Order on Customer.ID = Order.CustomerID
Where Order.CustomerID is Null
```

Basically you select all customers whether they have an Order or not (straight outer join) and then use where to filter out all those which have ordered something.

Try the above with and without the where clause, you'll see it.

PS don't use keywords as table names makes writing queries a PIA.